# How to get text from this html tag by using jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I meet a position when i using jsoup to extracting data. The data like this:

```
This is a <strong>strong</strong> number <date>2013</date>
```

I want to get data like this: `This is a number`

How can I do that? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can parse the html into a `Document`, select the `body`-Element and get its text.

**Example:**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("This is a <strong>strong</strong> number <date>2013</date>");

String ownText = doc.body().ownText();
String text = doc.body().text();

System.out.println(ownText);
System.out.println(text);
```

**Output:**

```
This is a number  
This is a strong number 2013
```

Comment: Is there any way to get "This is a ", "number" as separate text (not combined)?

Comment: You probably can split it by iterating over the underlying nodes.

Answer (score 3):

This should answer your question :

```
public String escapeHtml(String source) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(source);
    Elements elements = doc.select("b");
    for (Element element : elements) {
        element.replaceWith(new TextNode(element.toString(),""));
    }
    return Jsoup.clean(doc.body().toString(), new Whitelist().addTags("a").addAttributes("a", "href", "name", "rel", "target"));
}
```

[Jsoup - Howto clean html by escaping not deleting the unwanted html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756674/jsoup-howto-clean-html-by-escaping-not-deleting-the-unwanted-html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("This is a <strong>strong</strong> number <date>2013</date>");

Spanned HtmlDoc = Html.fromHtml(doc.toString());
String fromHTML = HtmlDoc.toString();

System.out.println(fromHTML);
```