# How to extract data from HTML-formatted EMail files via OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am working on a project where I have emailed receipts from various courier agents. The emails are of HTML format.

But, they do not all form a specific structure. Each email is of different format. I tried jsoup to extract data, but its difficult to write the extraction for each specific type of html. I need to extract Name, from location, to location, organization and few other details from the mail. I tried openNLP, but it does not recognize all locations and names. It catches some of the locations if it is in a sentence form.

Can I create my own training data with html content in it, annotate them and train it to detect locations and names based on the html structure i have in the training data?

Comment: No entity recogniser can do a perfect job. You should probably use a different tokenizer than the default. Training a recognizer model on HTML data won't help. I also do not understand why you should write an extraction for different HTML with Jsoup. There are too many aspects in the question, please make it more focused.

Comment: Entity recognizers will NOT learn structural information from HTML. From location and to location will always be locations and uniquely identified as locations. You may very well invest in writing regexes or jsoup rules for each currier type.

Answer (score 2):

I think your initial approach is worth pursuing. I see an option for 2 steps here:

1. Get the 'text' content of the mail using Jsoup. An example of that is here: [Get Text from html Using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946200/how-to-get-text-from-this-html-tag-by-using-jsoup).
2. Use OpenNLP or StanfordNLP NER to extract the named entities. Locations, Names e.t.c.

Another options involves playing around with the parse tree generated from the sentences and see if there is a pattern for the data you're open to extracting.

As regards getting `from location` and `to location`, you can try to generate a parse tree for the Sentences, there is an excellent example of that here: [Extract noun phrase from Sentences OpenNLP](https://gist.github.com/johnmiedema/e12e7359bcb17b03b8a0). Just change the code to get the `PP` (Prepositional Phrase) in `line 65` as it currently gets the NP (Noun Phrase).

You'll notice that `from location` and `to location` are prepositional phrases (from and to are prepositions). Once you get the prepositional phrases from the sentences, you can try to extract the noun component (after the preposition) and use other heuristics to determine if they are locations.

Something that can also be very useful is if you have a lexicon of the possible locations. If there is a lexicon then your 'search space' is smaller, you can check your prepositional phrases to see if they are known locations.

As someone mentioned in the comment, no entity recognizer can do a perfect job out of the box. These things usually need a lot of tweaking so you have to be keen on experimenting and looking at what the data says.

Hope this helps