# How to replace <a href='www.example.com'>Example：</a>?

Tags: java, html, replaceall

String url : `<a href='https://sample.com'>Example：</a>`

I want to keep text `Example`:
How to use replaceAll to do remove/replace with " "?

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regex syntax which is not right tool for that job (for reasons why see: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747), [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166)). To handle HTML use HTML parser like `jsoup` which lets us write code like [How to get text from this html tag by using jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15946200)

Comment: sorry~ I have this string input from user~ so i need to handle it for removing head and tail or just take the text out~

Comment: Solution from linked question seems to apply here. Check if `String replaced = Jsoup.parse(textFromUser).body().text();` does what you wanted (be sure to include to your application jsoup library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particularly for your case:

```
String url = "<a href='https://sample.com'>Example：</a>";
String text = url.replaceAll("<a.*>\\b", "").replaceAll("</a>", ""));
```

Comment: If space can be after `Example: ` there is also a risk that user will also add it (one or more) before it like `<a href='https://sample.com'> Example：</a>` in which case `.replaceAll("<a.*>\\b", "")` will fail. There are many traps which will need to be solved while writing regex solution. Better approach would be using tools *designed* to handle this kind of situations which is HTML parser.

Comment: the best comment ever! and also I find another way~~~

replaceAll("<a href='.+'>(.+)<\\/a>", "$1")

Comment: Pshemo, that's why I've declared the solution is particularly for this case.